# how to load wpf usercontrol in MVVM pattern

Tags: wpf, mvvm, user-controls

I'm creating a wpf user control which is in mvvm pattern.
So we have : view(with no code in codebehind file), viewmodel,model,dataaccess files.

I have **MainWindow**.xaml as a view file, which I need to bind with **MainWindowModel**.cs.

Usually, in a a wpf application we can do this with onStartUp event in App.xaml file. But in user control, as we do not have App.xaml...How do I achieve it ?

Please help :(...Thanks in Advance !!!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use a `ContentControl`, with a `DataTemplate` to bind the `UserControl` (View) to the ViewModel :

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:MyViewModel}">
    <v:MyUserControl />
</DataTemplate>

...

<ContentControl Content="{Binding Current}" />
```

WPF will pick the `DataTemplate` automatically based on the type of the `Content`

Comment: Dont we need any Property (dependency property or normal property )...in Content tag ?...Or How "Current" satisfies the same?

Comment: Hi Thomas, Can you please give me an idea about above query ?

Comment: In the code above, `Current` would be a property of the data context, of type `MyViewModel`

Comment: Will it intiatiate the instance of class "MyViewModel" ?
Also...hw the ContentControl know which DataTemplate it has to refer ?

Comment: No, it creates an instance of MyUserControl. Creating the instance of MyViewModel is your responsibility. The ContentControl picks the DataTemplate from the resources : it looks for a DataTemplate with the same DataType as the ViewModel and no x:Key attribute

Comment: If I have to create instance of "MyViewModel" ...I have to create it in code-behind file of "View" right ?

Comment: I don't know the structure of your code, so I can't really answer that... You could create it in the "parent" ViewModel (that's what I usually do)

Comment: If want to pass data to child control from parent control how to do that? as we are instantiating the viewModel from xaml?

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old, answered question, but I have a different approach. I like to make implicit relationships in the App.xaml file:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:KioskViewModel}">
        <Views:KioskView />
    </DataTemplate>
</Application.Resources>
```

With this, there is no need to set a DataContext anywhere.

UPDATE >>>

In response to @Vignesh Natraj's request, here is a fuller explanation:

Once you have set up the `DataTemplate` in a `Resources` element, you can display the `KioskView` in this example by adding an instance of the `KioskViewModel` anywhere in your XAML. This could be filling the `MainWindow`, or just inside a particular section of the screen. You could also host multiple instances of the `KioskViewModel` in a `ListBox` and it will generate multiple `KioskView` instances.

You can add an instance of the `KioskViewModel` to your XAML in a couple of ways, depending on your requirements. One way is to declare the XML namespace for the project that contains the `KioskViewModel.cs` file and simply add an instance of it in a `ContentControl` to the page where you want your view to appear. For example, if you had a `UserControl` called `MainView` and the `KioskViewModel.cs` file was in a `Kiosk.ViewModels` namespace, you could use basic XAML like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Kiosk.Views.MainView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:Kiosk.ViewModels">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ViewModels:KioskViewModel x:Key="KioskViewModel" />
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:KioskViewModel}">
            <Views:KioskView />
        </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource KioskViewModel}" />
</UserControl>
```

I prefer to use the MVVM design pattern with WPF, so I would have a base view model class providing useful functionality such as implementing the essential `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. I then have a property called `ViewModel` in the main (top level) view model of type `BaseViewModel`. This provides me with a nice way to change the `ViewModel` property to any view model that has derived from `BaseViewModel` and therefore to be able to change the associated view from the view model.

For example, in the `MainViewModel.cs` class that is bound to `MainView` there is a field and relating property:

```
private BaseViewModel viewModel = new KioskViewModel();
public BaseViewModel ViewModel
{
    get { return viewModel; }
    set { viewModel = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("ViewModel"); }
}
```

As you can see, it starts off as a `KioskViewModel` instance, but can be changed to any other view at any time in response to user interaction. For this setup, the XAML is very similar, but instead of declaring an instance of the view model in the `Resources` element, we bind to the property in the `MainViewModel`:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Kiosk.Views.MainView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:Kiosk.ViewModels">
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding ViewModel}" />
</UserControl>
```

Note that for this example, we would need to declare two (or more to make this approach useful) `DataTemplate`s in the `App.xaml` file:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:MainViewModel}">
        <Views:MainView />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:KioskViewModel}">
        <Views:KioskView />
    </DataTemplate>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: can you explain me how this works, I tried this, but nothing is getting binded to my view.
I know its old but thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I've been using [MVVM Light Toolkit](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/) which has a ViewModelLocator class that you can put properties to the viewmodels in. You then create a reference to the ViewModelLocator in your Mainwindow.xaml like so:

```
<vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" d:IsDataSource="True"/>
```

In the grid panel, or whatever you're using, you can then set the datacontext like this:

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding MainWindowViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
...
</Grid>
```

You could also go with [MEFedMVVM](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2010/04/24/an-introduction-to-mefedmvvm-part-1/) which potentially adds a bit more flexibility in terms of being able to swap different viewModel implementations into the view.

The flexibility in both of these libraries is that you don't have to use their ViewModel base classes if you don't want to - the ViewModelLocator and the MEFedMVVM can work with any class.

Answer (score 2):

There are endless ways to do it, wich all fall in one of the two categories:"view first" or "model first".

In a "view first" mode the view (e.g. your mainwindow) is created first and then (e.g. in the  codebehind) the View instantiates the ViewModel and sets it as its datacontext):

```
private void WindowLoaded(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
   this.DataContext = ViewModelService.GetViewModelX();
}
```

In a "model first" mode the ViewModel is there first and then instanciated the View.

```
// method of the viewmodel 
public void LoadView()
{
     // in this example the view abstracted using an interface
     this.View = ViewService.GetViewX();
     this.View.SetDataContext(this);
     this.View.Show();    
}
```

The examples given here are just one way of many. You could look at the various [MVVM frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1280462/what-mvvm-framework-are-you-using) and see how they do it.

Comment: In MVVM model can we have code in code behind  file of a view ?

Comment: Yes! A lot of implementations use the codebehind to wire-up the view with the viewmodel. For the sake of blendability and testability this should be kept at a minimum.

Answer (score 0):

We can use [ObjectDataProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.data.objectdataprovider) to call a method inside an object ..as follows :

```
<ObjectDataProvider ObjectType="{x:Type local:TemperatureScale}"
                    MethodName="ConvertTemp" 
                    x:Key="convertTemp">
```

Is there anyway to do the same using DataTemplate

Answer (score 0):

You can probably look at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521(v=vs.110).aspx). I find it as a good resource, though it doesn't explain how to use usercontrols,you will find your way out.