# Dynamically Load UserControl using MVVM Light Toolkit

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm-light, dynamic-usercontrols

I searched this site and i found 2 Links
[how to load wpf usercontrol in MVVM pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872156/how-to-load-wpf-usercontrol-in-mvvm-pattern)

[MVVM-Light: Load UserControl into Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3018849/mvvm-light-load-usercontrol-into-window)

but still i cant find the answer to my problem and this link

[MVVM-Light Locator Pattern and Reusable UserControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3097865/mvvm-light-locator-pattern-and-reusable-usercontrol)

i Didn't Understood.... so here is i am stating my problem which might help others struggling like me ......

I have a `MainWindow` which has 2 parts one has a `TreeView`(a 
`UserControl`) and the other Displays different user controls(named DisplayPanel).... just like windows Explorer.

The Display Panel on the Right side will display different user controls on Clicking nodes of tree view.

and my `TreeView` is Itself a user Control.

How can i make this composite UI Work using `MVVM`. Also I am planning to use `MVVM` light Toolkit. Does this have something that can help...

An Example will be great

Thanks... :)

Edit

My TreeView in a `UserControl` I made a dependency property in the `UserControl` which catches the selected Item fo the tree view so that i can use this dependency property to populate the required view in the "MainView" `ContentControl` binding....as you advised me in the comments. Everything is till now

Problem is that i want to display data contained in the  the selected item and i cannot set the DataContext of the UserControls(which will be displayed in right hand side) to the selected item as then i will not be able to use my view model for the respective usercontrol  for commands and other operations

I tried to solve this too.... i used the Mediator (Messenger) in my TreeViewUserControl view model to send a Message to the Usercontrol's(the one that  i need to display) view model . Message will be passed whenever the item is selected in the tree view. and message contains the selected node.  I forgot to mention i set the datacontext of the UserControl to its view model so that i could display data

But using this approach the problem is that when the I click a type of node for the first time the data is not populated but if the same type of node is clicked again its populated. What’s happening is that `UserControl`s object is availabe when the the tree item is clicked for the first time and Mediator sends the message. So Mediator is not able to pass the message to the userControl view model.....

I totally do not have ne idea to solve this further.... is my way if displaying user control right or I should do something that else....totally confused.....

Comment: Is that possible with MVVM or we have to break the pattern and use Code Behind.......I searched it all day today but didnt find ne thing useful. :(

Comment: i am not  specifically associating to MVVM light toolkit..... i could be ne solution..... if i could get one because its not letting me finish what i started.... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try defining a [DataTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate.aspx) for each type in the TreeView's [ItemsSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource.aspx) and instead of having a specific UserControl on the right side, just bind to the TreeView's [SelectedItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.treeview.selecteditem.aspx).  Alternatively, you could use a [DataTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector.aspx).

**Edited for OP's Edit**
Did you do this?

- `MainWindow` has TreeView whose `ItemsSource=Binding MainVM.Items`.
- `MainWindow` has ContentControl whose `Content=Binding TreeView.SelectedItem`.
- Somewhere in project, have `ResourceDictionary` where each possible type in `MainVM.Items` has a DataTemplate defined?

Which ViewModel (MainVM or ItemVM) are you trying to use and why can't you use it?

Comment: If I Understood correctly..... DataTemplateSelector Will Select the View For me Automatically based on Binding With Selected Item...???

Comment: How is it Done....??? All my View are UserControls which will be displayed on the Right side .... Each userControl have its own Functionality...I Just Need to Load the Right View With the Right Selected Node ...

Comment: Personally, here's what I would do: For each possible type in treeView.ItemsSource, Define a DataTemplate (in a ResourceDictionary), then on the right side, have a ContentControl Content=Binding treeView.SelectedItem.  With DataTemplate defined for **type** in a ResourceDictionary, when WPF sees **type**, it automatically creates what it should look like (from the DataTemplate).

Comment: Hi there , 

I tried your solution its worked well for me for some time until i ran into a prob.... may be its my fault that i am not able to use it properly i have described it in the question.....

Comment: I'm thinking: Click #1: the NodeVM isn't created yet, so TreeVM is sending a message with no receiver.  Click #2: the NodeVM is now created so TreeVM sends and NodeVM now receives.  Did you setup the Bindings like I suggested.  Why are you sending a message from TreeVM to NodeVM?